# How do you install mercurial when mercurial.selenic.com is down?

Tags: mercurial, mirror

I'm trying to install mercurial (the DVCS) but unfortunately http://mercurial.selenic.com is down.  Does anybody know of any mirrors I could grab the source from, allowing me to install it.  Hopefully the site doesn't stay down long, but doing some searching on twitter it appears it's already been down for a few days.

Comment: Use the package for your system? Mercurial is very popular, I'd be surprised to find a system that doesn't package it.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question I asked was quite specific, "Does anyone know of mirrors I can get the mercurial source from?"  I also got a great answer which means that it can be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Google for "mercurial mirror"?

Comment: Thanks I do see a bitbucket mirror now.  When I had googled before I had seen that a lot of the results were guides to setting up a mercurial mirror which wasn't what I was looking for and I suppose I got discouraged, which is why I came here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find necessary code with instructions here.
http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/stable (on this webpage left you can find two links to download sources in either gz or zip).
Everything what you need to do is written in README file.
But you can install it else using your package manager just by running

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Comment: I've been trying to do pip install mercurial but it's failing because mercurial.selenic.com is down.  I don't have access to sudo or apt on the particular platform (webfaction) so I'm looking for a link to the actual source download which is normally at mercurial.selenic.com/downloads

Comment: On this web-page left http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/  you can find two links to gz and zip archives with source code. Try downloading and installing.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.  I ended up using the stable branch, which is http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/stable/ but my google foo failed me earlier trying to find that.  If you update your answer with that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a copy from a mirror: http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/archive/2.5.2.tar.gz